# Write a query to find all intermittent clients (everyone with a 6 months gap between appointments, or people who have less than 2 appointments a year)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I was given a problem where I must return only the first and last name of clients who have either

1. a greater than 6 months gap between appointments
2. 2 or less appointments per year

For **every** year existing in the appointments table. 
Here is the create for the appointments table and client table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointments](
[pk_appointments] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[k_client_info] [int] NOT NULL,
[date] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[client_info](
[pk_client_info] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[first_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[last_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[phone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My thought was to write two queries that satisfies both 1 and 2, and union them together. I have 2. as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
FROM client_info
LEFT JOIN appointments ON pk_client_info = k_client_info
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, k_client_info, year(date)
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
```

But I'm having some troubles wrapping my head around how to write the query that would satisfy 1, which is find all clients with a greater than 6 month gap between appointments. I thought about running a select on the client_info table and joining on the appointment table twice and somehow get them to line up and be in the right order so that I can compare the dates. Perhaps I need to do a `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTION BY k_client_info?`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I would think about a structure with two sub-queries in the WHERE clause and an OR between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a1.k_client_info

FROM [dbo].[Appointments] a1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT top 1 a2.[date], a2.[pk_appointments] 
                    FROM [dbo].[Appointments] a2 
                    WHERE a1.k_client_info = a2.k_client_info AND a1.[date] > a2.[date] 
                    order by a2.[date] DESC) a3
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, a3.[date], a1.[date]) >= 6

UNION ALL

SELECT k_client_info
FROM [dbo].[Appointments]
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE), k_client_info
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

- left outer Join the appointment table to itself on t1.pk_client_info = t2.pk_client_info
  and t1.date > t2.date
- Find the maximum t2.date - this will give you for each appointment the last appointment prior.

From the resulting set,

select k_client_info, group by k_client_info, having min(datediff(mm, date, prior_date)) > 5